# How to find RegEx with inurl: Parameter in Google Search?

Tags: regex, parameters, google-search

I try to find urls with wrong patterns in the Google Index. Is it possible to find a RegEx with inurl: Parameter in Google Search?

As Example:

- http://tld/post-url/\d+
- http://tld/post-url/\d+/.*

Comment: hmm, ok, so inurl does not accept any wildcards :(

Comment: This answers your question I guess; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-google-using-regular-expressions-regex